# How to test load on Set of different API's

Tags: rest, jmeter, soapui, load-testing, web-api-testing

I am doing load testing in Soap ui and working on cab booking application so set api like this for example

```
userSingin ,GetlocationDetails,bookCab,getDriverDetails,acceptRide and completeRide so on.
```

It will become on loop(on completing of one ride successfully ) so this seniors may  happened like  1000 or 10000 times.

The question is  how to interlink api do it a single entity and perform load test using soap ui,  jmeter or any load testing tools,or by coding  please help me sort out problem with simple demo.

Comment: Can you show your existing Soap UI tests, currently with provided informations it is impossible to understand

Comment: Ok i got Point and  please dont go for  test case understand the requirement  here one api is there like  example htttp://uber.in/SingIn and http://uber.in/getlocation and http://uber.in/driverlocation (also consisting of json request and response)  so like these set of api is there how to make call one by one api and make one  loop as happens in  cab booking  app. and get in one entity and test on load that entity for 1000 user. so these is the problem how to sort this. and one more thing  i am not working uber just for your understanding i used uber

Comment: Do not change your question to something completely different once it's been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. SoapUI has [some load testing capabilities](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/concept.html) so given you have a functional test ready you can run it with increased load.
2. If SoapUI's load testing is not enough (i.e. you cannot create the desired load or find results not too verbose/informative) you can build the same test plan using JMeter's [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers. If you need to send custom [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and [SOAPAction](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/unraveling_the_mystery_of_soap.html) headers - it can be done via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). See [Building a SOAP WebService Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-ws-test-plan.html) article for more details.
3. Last but not the least, you can either execute existing SoapUI project using JMeter using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool, see [SoapUI Support](http://gettaurus.org/docs/SoapUI/) for more details on the specific feature and [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) to get familiarized with the tool and its concept.